# SQL Server integration test validating datetime created with AutoFixture

Tags: c#, sql-server, integration-testing, autofixture

I am creating integration test for my repository. I use `AutoFixture` to create a `Notification` which should be inserted with a `NotificationRepository`.

`Notification` has a property `Processed` which is a `DateTime`. When `AutoFixture` creates the date, it is created with very precise values.

SQL Server does not have the same precision as .Net so you sometimes miss a millisecond when inserting the date into SQL Server and so my test has a hard time validationg the result. I use semantic comparison to check if the inserted value is correct.

How can I configure `AutoFixture` to create dates with the same precision as SQL Server?

### Current code

```
[Test]
public void InsertShouldInsertNotification()
{
    var sut = new NotificationRepository(TestConnectionString);
    var notification = fixture.Build<Notification>().Without(x => x.Id).Create();

    sut.Insert(notification);

    var result = sut.Get(notification.Id);
    notification.AsSource().OfLikeness<Notification>().ShouldEqual(result);
}

public enum DocumentStatus
{
    New = 0,
    InSigning = 1,
    Cancelled = 2,
    Signed = 3,
    InReview = 4,
    Reviewed = 5,
    Deleted = 6,
    Rejected = 7
}

public class Notification
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string Metadata { get; set; }
    public DocumentStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Processed { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer, you should use `DATETIME2(3)` instead of `DATETIME` to get the same millisecond precision as .NET has. `DATETIME` has a 3.33ms precision - `DATETIME2(n)` can have a precision of up to 7 digits after the second - up to 100ns, if needed. `n = 3` corresponds to millisecond precision

Comment: The built-in `DateTime` value type has the precision it has, and you can't change that. It's a type defined by the BCL so AutoFixture can't change its precision. If you can't use `DATETIME2(3)` as suggested by @marc_s, your repository implementation *will* exhibit loss of precision, and your tests need to take that into account.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, DATETIME2(3) sounds good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in `DateTime` value type has the precision it has, and you can't change that. It's a type defined by the BCL so AutoFixture can't change its precision. If you can't use `DATETIME2(3)` as suggested by @marc_s in the comments, your repository implementation will exhibit loss of precision, and your tests need to take that into account.

One way to do that is to add a custom comparer of `DateTime` values that has a built-in tolerance factor. You could, for example, implement [`IEqualityComparer<DateTime>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151).

Some assertion libraries allow you to pass in a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`; e.g. xUnit.net. This would enable you to write something like:

```
Assert.Equal(expected, actual, new TolerantDateTimeComparer());
```

where `TolerantDateTimeComparer` is your custom implementation of `IEqualityComparer<DateTime>`.

Comment: Thank you Mark, great answer :)